# Formatting JSON output in wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have this function that queries a wordpress database table:

```
    public function generateJson() {
        if (isset($_POST['update_json'])) {

            global $wpdb;
            $map_rows = $wpdb->get_results(
                    'select f.floor_id, f.floor_title,
                        f.floor_map,m.id,m.type,m.title,
                        m.about,m.description,m.icon,m.link,
                        m.xcord,m.ycord,m.type,m.link
                        from wp_infokiosksfloors f, 
                        wp_infokiosksmap m 
                        where f.floor_id = m.floor');

            // json_encode($args);

            $map = array();
            $args = array();
            foreach ($map_rows as $locations => $location) {
                //$map[] = $value->id;

                      $args= [
                          'mapwidth' => '800',
                          'mapheight' => '600',
                    'level' => array([
                            'id' =>$location->floor_id,
                            'title' => $location->floor_title,
                            'map' => $location->floor_map,
                            "locations" => array([
                                    'id' => $location->id,
                                    'title' => $location->title,
                                    'about' => $location->about,
                                    'description' => $location->description,
                                    'subcategory' =>$location->type,
                                    'link' => $location->link,
                                    'icon' => $location->icon,
                                    'x' => $location->xcord,
                                    'y' => $location->ycord
                                ])
                        ])
                ];



          echo json_encode($args, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT.JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

            }


            echo "<h4 style='color:red'>Map locations successfully updated</h4>";
        }
        $fp = '../wp-content/themes/xxx/js/map/infomap.json';
        return   file_put_contents($fp, json_encode($args, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT.JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
    }
```

I want it to output a json similar to the following format:

```
{
    "mapwidth": "800",
    "mapheight": "600",
    "levels": [
        {
            "id": "second",
            "title": "Second Floor",
            "map": "../img/map/02-plain.svg",
            "minimap": "images/mall/mall-basement-small.jpg",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "id": "gateA",
                    "title": "Gate 15",
                    "about": "Gate 15",
                    "description": "Gate 15",
                    "category": "flights",
                    "subcategory": "allgate",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-flight-departures.svg",
                    "link":"",
                    "x": "0.6342",
                    "y": "0.4433"
                },
                {
                    "id": "gateb",
                    "title": "Gate 16",
                    "about": "Gate 16",
                    "description": "Gate 16",
                    "category": "gate",
                    "subcategory": "allgate",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-flight-departures.svg",
                    "x": "0.5273",
                    "y": "0.5323"
                },
                {
                    "id": "gatec",
                    "title": "Gate 18",
                    "about": "Gate 18",
                    "description": "Gate 18",
                    "category": "gate",
                    "subcategory": "allgate",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-flight-departures.svg",
                    "x": "0.3923",
                    "y": "0.6170"
                },
                {
                    "id": "gated",
                    "title": "Gate 19",
                    "about": "Gate 19",
                    "description": "Gate 19",
                    "category": "gate",
                    "subcategory": "allgate",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-flight-departures.svg",
                    "x": "0.3720",
                    "y": "0.6807"
                },
                {
                    "id": "gatee",
                    "title": "Gate 20",
                    "about": "Gate 20",
                    "description": "Gate 20",
                    "category": "gate",
                    "subcategory": "allgate",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-flight-departures.svg",
                    "x": "0.4117",
                    "y": "0.7462"
                },
                {
                    "id": "gatef",
                    "title": "Gate 21",
                    "about": "Gate 21",
                    "description": "Gate 21",
                    "category": "gate",
                    "subcategory": "allgate",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-flight-departures.svg",
                    "x": "0.5547",
                    "y": "0.5846"
                },
                {
                    "id": "gateg",
                    "title": "Gate 22",
                    "about": "Gate 22",
                    "description": "Gate 22",
                    "category": "gate",
                    "subcategory": "allgate",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-flight-departures.svg",
                    "x": "0.6190",
                    "y": "0.5272"
                },
                {
                    "id": "jcafe",
                    "title": "Java Cafe",
                    "about": "Luke's Java Cafe",
                    "description": "Has the best of both international and local coffee",
                    "category": "restaurant",
                    "subcategory": "all-restaurant",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-leisure-bar.svg",
                    "link": "",
                    "x": "0.7079",
                    "y": "0.4009"
                },
                {
                    "id": "jcafe2",
                    "title": "Java Cafe",
                    "about": "Luke's Java Cafe",
                    "description": "Has the best of both international and local coffee",
                    "category": "restaurant",
                    "subcategory": "all-restaurant",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-leisure-bar.svg",
                    "link": "",
                    "x": "0.4794",
                    "y": "0.6521"
                },
                {
                    "id": "jcafe3",
                    "title": "Java Cafe",
                    "about": "Luke's Java Cafe",
                    "description": "Has the best of both international and local coffee",
                    "category": "restaurant",
                    "subcategory": "all-restaurant",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-leisure-bar.svg",
                    "link": "",
                    "x": "0.6775",
                    "y": "0.2986"
                },
                {
                    "id": "toilet",
                    "title": "Toilets",
                    "about": "Toilets, Washrooms",
                    "description": "Clean and nice toilets",
                    "category": "services",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-toilet.svg",
                    "x": "0.6680",
                    "y": "0.2049"
                },
                {
                    "id": "toilet1",
                    "title": "Toilets",
                    "about": "Toilets, Washrooms",
                    "description": "Clean and nice toilets",
                    "category": "services",
                    "subcategory": "all-toilet",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-toilet.svg",
                    "x": "0.6572",
                    "y": "0.4097"
                },
                {
                    "id": "toilet2",
                    "title": "Toilets",
                    "about": "Toilets, Washrooms",
                    "description": "Clean and nice toilets",
                    "category": "services",
                      "subcategory": "all-toilet",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-toilet.svg",
                    "x": "0.8553",
                    "y": "0.5480"
                },
                {
                    "id": "toilet3",
                    "title": "Toilets",
                    "about": "Toilets, Washrooms",
                    "description": "Clean and nice toilets",
                    "category": "services",
                      "subcategory": "all-toilet",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-toilet.svg",
                    "x": "0.8851",
                    "y": "0.5862"
                },
                {
                    "id": "toilet5",
                    "title": "Toilets",
                    "about": "Toilets, Washrooms",
                    "description": "Clean and nice toilets",
                    "category": "services",
                      "subcategory": "all-toilet",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-toilet.svg",
                    "x": "0.6562",
                    "y": "0.5049"
                },
                 {
                    "id": "toilet6",
                    "title": "Toilets",
                    "about": "Toilets, Washrooms",
                    "description": "Clean and nice toilets",
                    "category": "services",
                    "subcategory": "all-toilet",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-toilet.svg",
                    "x": "0.4042",
                    "y": "0.6744"
                },
                 {
                    "id": "infodesk",
                    "title": "Information Desk",
                    "about": "Enquiries",
                    "description": "Ask all you need to know",
                    "category": "services",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-infocenter.svg",
                    "x": "0.7312",
                    "y": "0.3607"
                },
                 {
                    "id": "counter1",
                    "title": "Counter",
                    "about": "Counter",
                    "description": "Counter",
                    "category": "services",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-counter-bpass.svg",
                    "x": "0.5808",
                    "y": "0.5613"
                },
                 {
                    "id": "counter2",
                    "title": "Counter",
                    "about": "Counter",
                    "description": "Counter",
                    "category": "services",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-counter-bpass.svg",
                    "x": "0.5228",
                    "y": "0.6109"
                },
                 {
                    "id": "counter3",
                    "title": "Counter",
                    "about": "Counter",
                    "description": "Counter",
                    "category": "services",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-counter-bpass.svg",
                    "x": "0.4488",
                    "y": "0.6800"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "third",
            "title": "Third Floor",
            "map": "../img/map/03-plain.svg",
            "minimap": "images/mall/mall-basement-small.jpg",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "id": "viplounge",
                    "title": "Vip Lounge",
                    "about": "VIP Lounge: Restricted area",
                    "description": "Entry to this location is under restriction",
                    "category": "restaurant",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-viplounge.svg",
                    "link": "",
                    "x": "0.4484",
                    "y": "0.7046"
                },
                 {
                    "id": "jcafe4",
                    "title": "Java Cafe",
                    "about": "Luke's Java Cafe",
                    "description": "Has the best of both international and local coffee",
                    "category": "restaurant",
                    "subcategory": "all-restaurant",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-leisure-bar.svg",
                    "link": "",
                    "x": "0.6775",
                    "y": "0.2986"
                },
                {
                    "id": "toilet9",
                    "title": "Toilets",
                    "about": "Toilets, Washrooms",
                    "description": "Clean and nice toilets",
                    "category": "services",
                    "subcategory": "all-toilet",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-toilet.svg",
                    "x": "0.7252",
                    "y": "0.4460"
                },
                {
                    "id": "toilet10",
                    "title": "Toilets",
                    "about": "Toilets, Washrooms",
                    "description": "Clean and nice toilets",
                    "category": "services",
                    "subcategory": "all-toilet",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-toilet.svg",
                    "x": "0.4699",
                    "y": "0.5975"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "first",
            "title": "First Floor",
            "map": "../img/map/01-plain.svg",
            "minimap": "images/mall/mall-first-small.jpg",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "id": "shopfirst",
                    "title": "Darwy Shopping Collection",
                    "about": "All kinds of shopping",
                    "description": "Find ",
                    "category": "restaurant",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-leisure-shop.svg",
                    "link": "",
                    "x": "0.5402",
                    "y": "0.5561"
                },
                 {
                    "id": "jcafe5",
                    "title": "Java Cafe",
                    "about": "Luke's Java Cafe",
                    "description": "Has the best of both international and local coffee",
                    "category": "restaurant",
                    "subcategory": "all-restaurant",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-leisure-bar.svg",
                    "link": "",
                    "x": "0.4090",
                    "y": "0.7126"
                },
                {
                    "id": "toilet7",
                    "title": "Toilets",
                    "about": "Toilets, Washrooms",
                    "description": "Clean and nice toilets",
                    "category": "services",
                    "subcategory": "all-toilet",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-toilet.svg",
                    "x": "0.8863",
                    "y": "0.4737"
                },
                {
                    "id": "toilet8",
                    "title": "Toilets",
                    "about": "Toilets, Washrooms",
                    "description": "Clean and nice toilets",
                    "category": "services",
                    "subcategory": "all-toilet",
                    "icon": "../img/map/icon-toilet.svg",
                    "x": "0.4687",
                    "y": "0.5995"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Only the first part appears as follows:

```
{
    "mapwidth": "800",
    "mapheight": "600",
    "level": [{
            "id": "Second",
            "title": "Second Floor",
            "map": wp-content/uploads/2014/08/hotel.jpg",
            "locations": [{
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "My Barber",
                    "about": "Barber shop",
                    "description": "Barber shop",
                    "subcategory": "ATMs",
                    "link": "",
                    "icon": "wp-content/uploads/2014/08/hotel.jpg",
                    "x": "54.75",
                    "y": "64.55"
                }]
        }]
}
```

Could someone please help me how I can go about this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `$args= [` to `$args[] = [`.

In case of `$args= [`, you replace the value of `$args` every time in the loop. In case of `$args[] = [` you add a new item to the `$args` array.